# Trouble using inputted variable with dplyr in Shiny with a reactive dataset

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, reactive

I have browsed the other answers regarding issues with plyr and dplyr without success.

I want to use two inputted variables in the dplyr "group_by_" and "summarise" commands.  I can not seem to find the right syntax to input my variable into summarise to get a mean with the grouping.  Turning it back into a data frame doesn't work.

```
new_frame <- frame() 
new_frame[[input$ycol]]
```

sapply gives a result but it ignores the grouping levels and gives me the mean of the entire column.

```
mean = sapply(frame()[input$ycol],mean)
```

I am not sure what other options to use.

MWE with error as follows.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("MWE using faithful data"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', "",choices = "colour"),
        selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "",choices = c("waiting", "eruptions"))),

      mainPanel(
         tableOutput("distPlot"))))

server <- function(input, output) {

  frame <- reactive({

    faithful <- faithful %>% mutate(colour = rep(c("red","white"),136))
    return(faithful)
  })

   output$distPlot <- renderTable({
     frame() %>% group_by_(input$xcol) %>% 
       summarise(mean = mean(input$ycol))
   })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I hard code the line

```
summarise(mean = mean(input$ycol))
```

to

```
summarise(mean = mean(eruptions))
```

Using summarise_ is no good either.

it gives me what I want, but that is not an option in my actual code.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is how we are evaluating the `input$xcol` and `input$ycol`.  These are string elements.  One option is to convert it to symbol with `rlang::sym` and evalute with `!!`

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("MWE using faithful data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', "",choices = "colour"),
      selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "",choices = c("waiting", "eruptions"))),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("distPlot"))))

server <- function(input, output) {

  frame <- reactive({

  faithful %>%
           mutate(colour = rep(c("red","white"),136))

  })

  output$distPlot <- renderTable({
       frame() %>%
            group_by(!! rlang::sym(input$xcol)) %>% 
            summarise(mean = mean(!! rlang::sym(input$ycol)))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer.  What are the other options you mention?